# Why is Views Nivo Slideshow block only displaying to logged in users?

Tags: views, javascript

I'm using the Views Nivo Slider module to create a slideshow for a couple of different sites I'm creating. The slideshow works perfectly if a user is logged in, but the block doesn't display at all when not logged in (the HTML for the block isn't even there). I thought it might be a permissions issue, so I tried giving anonymous users every permission possible, and still no luck. Any idea what might be causing this? Could it be something in my view?

Comment: Did you check the permissions for your view (on the view itself)?  If you set the permissions to a role on the view, even giving anonymous users permissions would not allow them to access the view unless they had the role.

Comment: I checked, but the access is set to Unrestricted.

Comment: Have you tried first clearing cache data and then giving permission ?

Comment: Is anonym able to view content or entities from your view?

Answer (score 0):

I have some problems with blocks before and I always check the following, it has solved my problems so far.

- Check your block permission.
- Verify the block is assigned to a valid region setting in your template.
- Rebuild the node permissions in admin/reports/status. Before doing this, backup your database and clear the cache.
- Verify the access permission used from the view is *view published content*.

When I am working with views, I make sure the theme developer module is not enabled. I disable it, and then I clear the cache.

Answer (score 0):

Check the advanced settings, and try to disable views sql rewriting.